# "Windowns Setting": Result from Win 10 search bar

Tags: windows-10, search, malware

The question is whether the search bar result displaying an unlikely spelling error can be ignored or is a clue to the presence of something malicious.

It began with my need to know more about removing orphan entries in the Start menu. So from Edge, I searched and got this [info](https://prntscr.com/TWhmoMJ6TaSt)
[https://www.bing.com/search?q=windows%2010%20start%20menu%20not%20working%20site:microsoft.com&form=B00032&ocid=SettingsHAQ-BingIA&mkt=en-US](https://prntscr.com/TWhmoMJ6TaSt)
which included this text:

> Press Windows logo Start button key + R, type ms-settings:, and then select OK. This opens Settings

Then I highlighted and copied just the text 'ms-settings' (leaving out the colon and comma.) After hitting the Win key and pasting, what appeared was this:

[image: screenshot]

The spelling error would not have raised my eyebrows if this were from some random website. But the link directly below and apparently in the same box shows an official Microsoft website. I'm not used to seeing MS publish glaring instances of spelling errors involving their own products, so I had an uh-oh moment. The link seems to go to a real MS site where I found no such spelling error. So I want to know, is there any good reason to suspect malware as a probable source, or am I not alone in getting this corrupt spelling result? If the latter turns out to be true and it can be called a non-threat, I will accept that and go on. Otherwise, I would like any helpful info about the nature of the threat and how one might best deal with it, especially if it is something new and newly unleashed. Various searches yielded no reference to this error which adds to my suspicion. Please report if my result is reproducible, then this can be closed.

Comment: Hello, is that the link? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/find-settings-in-windows-10-6ffbef87-e633-45ac-a1e8-b7a834578ac6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is whether the search bar result displaying an unlikely spelling error can be ignored or is a clue to the presence of something malicious.  If the latter turns out to be true and it can be called a non-threat, I will accept that and go on.

I was quickly able to recreate the reported behavior on my system.  The simplest explanation is that at one time, the page's title contained a spelling mistake which was fixed after Bing cataloged the page.  Looking at the page's source, linked in the Windows search result, proves the page is legitimate and does not contain the spelling mistake.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `ms-settings` in my Windows 10 Start menu and Microsoft
does not do such spelling mistakes, so I advise to be very very
careful.

I suggest to :

- Right-click the Start menu entry of `ms-settings` and select
  "Open file location" to find where it resides
- If this folder is not `System32`, add a screenshot of it to
  your post
- If there is an executable, right-click it and check its Properties
- Also upload the executable to
  [Virus Total](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload)
  to have it checked by dozens of antiviruses
- Deep-scan your computer with several well-known anti-viruses
  including Defender and
  [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).

Comment: I was easily able to recreate the reported behavior on my system.  My system most certainly is not infected nor is it compromised in any capacity. The screenshot is that of the search bar anyways.